# Initiating a dialog as a result of another dialog using SimpleDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I try to initiate a new dialog as a result of the previous one using SimpleDialog for JQuery Mobile but it won't work on my Android phone (Samsung Galaxy SII, Android 2.3.6). In a desktop browser it works.

It should show me the Second dialog after OK is pressed on the first, but it just won't.

I use the following code now to test it:

```
$("#Home").simpledialog({
    'mode': 'bool',
    'prompt': 'First Dialog To Show',
    'useModal': true,        
    'allowReopen': true,
    'onClosed': function () {
        alert("This Alert Gets Shown");
        $("#Home").simpledialog({
            'mode': 'bool',
            'prompt': 'Seconds Dialog To Show',
            'useModal': true,
            'allowReopen': true,           
            'onClosed': function () {
                //alert("bloces");

            },
            'buttons': {
                'OK': {
                    click: function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    },
    'buttons': {
        'OK': {
            click: function () {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog Ok button event = function(){ WaitUntilDialogsAreClosed("your callback")}

function WaitUntilDialogsAreClosed(Callback)
{
var contition = function(){return $.mobile.sdCurrentDialog}

    if (contition() == false) {
        setTimeout(function(){WaitUntil(contition, Callback)}, 500)
    }
    else {
            Callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this code at all. Can someone please explain further? Where do this code go, given the above example?